# Eclipse Luna Not Working (Kali Linux)

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-luna

Every time go to run the Linux Version of Eclipse Luna SR2, it just stops at the little Splash Screen (The window that comes up before you select your work space) and it just stays like that for about 30 seconds, and then closes. Any help please?

It generates this error log which is found [Here](http://pastebin.com/wVGg5Ehj)

Comment: I would try upgrading the default java version to 8.  It can be run with 1.6 compliance if necessary - I often use 1.7 compliance.  If that does not work, try doing a new download and verify its checksum.

Comment: @TrisNefzger
I looked up what java version i was using, and it say's i'm already running 1.6.0_34. This is what shows up when I type `java -version` in the terminal:
 `java version "1.6.0_34"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.6) (6b34-1.13.6-1~deb7u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)`

Comment: @TrisNefzger I did what you said an i updated the JRE(to JDK1.8.0_40) and it just prints out another error code.

Here is the new one: pastebin.com/GySgc2dn

Comment: see replyt in Answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Answer:  This is a known bug and a workaround that has fixed the issue in at least one case is to run

```
export SWT_GTK3=0
```

before starting Eclipse.  See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430736 for more information. If this workaround does not fix your issue make sure GTK3 is installed and upgrade glibc to at least version 2.14 to ensure Eclipse uses it. Apparently when Eclipse detects an older glibc it tries to use GTK2. If none of these suggestions fix your issue you should submit a bug report at http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp to work it out with the Eclipse development team and also to help inform other people about it.

@ElectroMan - This got too long for a comment. Yes, the error log says the same thing. That means you are running Java 6, "JRE version: 6.0_34-b34" according to the log. I suggest you try running Java 8 or at least Java 7. Java SE 8u40 is the current release from Oracle and it can be downloaded for 64 bit Linux from a link on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html. It is best to use the latest Oracle release and get away from the OpenJDK version, especially one that is two major releases outdated. However, if you opt for Java 7 its final release is available at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html. You should be able to install either in a non-default location and keep OpenJDK 1.6.0_34 as your main version of Java on your platform. Eclipse can be configured to use Java 8 or 7 after it is installed by project or as its default for all new projects, but the main thing is to tell it to use Java 8 or 7 when it runs, since it is a Java application. Some instructions for this are at http://www.cs.umd.edu/eclipse/install_java8_luna.html. One of the main reasons for upgrading from Eclipse Kepler to Luna is to get built-in Java 8 support. Another option is to follow the instructions in the error log and file a bug report at http://www.cs.umd.edu/eclipse/install_java8_luna.html and wait for a reply. Or maybe there is already a new Luna update and you could try it.